# Brave bookmarks disappear after visiting a site

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bookmarks, brave

When I go to a website by entering address or clicking on a bookmark bookmarks disappear.
When I open a new instance of the browser bookmarks are there, but then it goes like that again.
I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and enable "Show Bookmarks". This will show bookmarks on websites as well as new tab pages.